# Animated TV show where a high schooler turns into a creature, and fights another student from his school with the same ability

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

I think this show was on Disney XD, Cartoon Network, or Nickelodeon but I didn't find it on the list of shows. I saw it sometime between 2009 and 2013. Don't remember too many details and I don't know if things are blending together from other shows. It was an action type of show, but not anime style.

There was a guy in high school and I think he was either hiding that he could transform into a creature or he got his "powers" then. I feel like he might have drank something like orange juice but it actually wasn't.

He ended up fighting another dude in his high school who was the same thing as him. He might have grown a tail when he changed and he could change into the creature whenever he wanted to. I think the fight happened at the high school.

I'm super frustrated because I can't remember the name of it and have searched on IMDb and other platforms and haven't found anything. I know I would recognize it if I see it.

Comment: Could this have been the Toonami segment on Cartoon Network?  They do change up their title lineup from time to time...

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you have any sense of the animation style, i.e. whether this was Japanese animation, or western? Also, can you described the appearance/colours of the main creature/s?

Comment: "It's not an anime style show, though." Well, that lets out any of the various *Dragonball* variants I was thinking of (Goku has a tail the first time he transforms).

Comment: It's not an anime style show. The style of the characters are more realistic. Not like exaggerate big head and small bodies. They're mostly proportioned. They didn't look flat...like I feel like Avatar: The Last Airbender is more of a flat looking animation, to me. This show was more 3D looking. As for the colors, I don't remember much.

Comment: When you say the show was "more 3D looking", does that mean the animation was computer-generated? Or was it hand-drawn animation?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be *[American Dragon Jake Long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Dragon:_Jake_Long)*? It has the high school student who can turn into a creature, who fights others with similar abilities.

> Set in the New York City borough of Manhattan, this animated series tells the story of a Chinese-American Jake Long (voiced by Dante Basco), who must balance ordinary adolescence with the power and ability to change into a dragon. When he eventually unlocks his full potential and turns into the American Dragon, he has to overcome obstacles to protect the magical creatures living in the city, but as his ordinary self, Jake has issues with his deep crush on his schoolmate Rose (Mae Whitman) who, unbeknownst to Jake, has a dark, magical secret of her own: she is a natural dragon-slayer known as the Huntsgirl, a member of the Huntsclan, a cult of ninjas that slays mythical creatures and who Jake has fought consistently. The leader of the Huntsclan is the Huntsman (Jeff Bennett) who raised Rose.
>
> Jake navigates the city with his two best friends – Trixie Carter (Miss Kittie) and Arthur P. "Spud" Spudinski (Charlie Finn). When Jake gets home, it is to an extended family who all live together: Jake, his sister, their parents, and Jake's grandfather (his mother's father.) Jonathan (Jeff Bennett), a businessman dad originally from the Midwest, is unaware that he is married into a family of dragons from his Chinese wife Susan (Lauren Tom) (who lacks any dragon abilities, as she skipped her generation). Jake's maternal grandfather Lao Shi (Keone Young) trains his grandson in the magical, mystical ways of the dragons. Jake also cares very deeply for his annoying, overachieving, and seemingly perfect younger sister Hayley (Amy Bruckner) (a nascent dragon), despite feeling like he's stuck in her small shadow. Grandpa's cynical sidekick, a magical talking Shar-Pei named Fu Dog (John DiMaggio), is Jake's animal guardian and other best friend.

### Theme Song

Comment: No, it's not this show.

Comment: No worries. What does and does not match?

Answer (score 1):

Team Toon??? It matches your description and it was made 2013

Comment: You should add some details about this to show how it matches the question.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be *firebreather*? I felt that's the show i was looking as well, but it might not be the same one, but your 3D looking animation description does fits firebreather. (It's a movie from Cartoon network).